# How to find all C functions starting with a prefix in a library

Tags: c, windows, shell, posix

For a small test framework, I want to do automatic test discovery. Right now, my plan is that all tests just have a prefix, which could basically be implemented like this

```
#define TEST(name) void TEST_##name(void)
```

And be used like this (in different c files)

```
TEST(one_eq_one) { assert(1 == 1); }
```

The ugly part is that you would need to list all test-names again in the main function.

Instead of doing that, I want to collect all tests in a library (say lib-my-unit-tests.so) and generate the main function automatically, and then just link the generated main function against the library. All of this internal action can be hidden nicely with cmake.

So, I need a script that does:

```
1. Write "int main(void) {"
2. For all functions $f starting with 'TEST_' in lib-my-unit-tests.so do
  a) write "extern void $f(void);"
  b) write "$f();
3. Write "}"
```

Most parts of that script are easy, but I am unsure how to reliably get a list of all functions starting with the prefix.
On POSIX systems, I can try to parse the output of `nm`. But here, I am not sure if the names will always be the same (on my MacBook, all names start with an additional '_'). To me, it looks like it might be OS/architecture-dependent which names will be generated for the binary. For windows, I do not yet have an idea on how to do that.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to implement test-discovery in C? (maybe something like `dlsym`)
2. How do I reliably get a list of all function-names starting with a certain prefix on a MacOS/Linux/Windows

---

A partial solution for the problem is parsing `nm` with a regex:

```
for line in $(nm $1) ; do
    # Finds all functions starting with "TEST_" or "_TEST_"
    if [[ $line =~ ^_?(TEST_.*)$ ]] ; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done
```

And then a second script consumes this output to generate a c file that calls these functions. Then, cmake calls the second script to create the test executable

```
  add_executable(test-executable generated_source.c)
  target_link_libraries(test-executable PRIVATE library_with_test_functions)
  add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT generated_source.c
        COMMAND second_script.sh library_with_test_functions.so > generated_source.c
        DEPENDS second_script.sh library_with_test_functions)
```

I think this works on POSIX systems, but I don't know how to solve it for Windows

Comment: The C language does not have any built-in introspective capabilities.  If you want to do as you describe then you will need to look into extra-lingual tools such as, yes, `nm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script using the `nm` or `objdump` utilities to list the symbols, pipe through `awk` to select the appropriate name and output the desired source lines.

Comment: Yes, but how do I reliably parse `nm` for this? IIRC it has different formats on MacOS / Linux and the generated names are architecture independent.

Comment: Indeed the format differs on macOS and Linux, and so do the file formats. The script can test which OS is it running on and parse the output appropriately.